# Story Identification: human to animal transmutation

Tags: story-identification, anime

Lately I have a persistent and vague memory of a scene, maybe from an anime, which I cannot even contextualize, which I watched not so long ago. It is very probably about revenge and human-to-animal transmutation.

The scene I remember is the following: there is a big, splendid palace (kind of liberty-styled), in which some rich people, maybe nobles, are having a ball/banquet. Suddenly a curtain drops(?) and many wild animals appear, making the viewer to realize that they were humans not so long ago. I have the sensation that the nobles / rich people themselves were transformed into animals in order to enact a revenge against their evil behavior in a kind of ironic way. The palace is finally seen from the distance, set to fire, in a final act of grace.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I'm sadly not even sure it was an anime, so I am reluctant in adding some maybe improper tags. I made it less vague as I could. Anyway, if some other details come to my mind, I will add them for sure!

Comment: @Alex Doe It seems to me that setting a building on fire is not "an act of grace" but an act of anger or an act of vengence or an act of cruelty, etc.

Comment: @M.A.Golding In my memory, the fact of being turned into irrational animals (they were showed while screaming, etc.) was a punishment and the dead was a better destiny than that. But, of course, I may remember wrong or it could be just my interpretation. Anyway, it was surely done inside an act of vengeance